# Configuring the Runtime Policy in Glimpse MVC4 , EF6

Tags: glimpse

I used the **runtimepolicies** element in my web.Config file to configure the runtime policy.

But when run the application give a run-time exception like below.

**Parser Error Message: Unrecognized element 'runtimepolicies'.**

Please give me your support to configure the runtime policy in the Glimpse correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this, is by going to [yoursite]/glimpse.axd and use the configuration tool on the right side.

You can then check and uncheck wanted or unwanted runtime policies, tabs,... and it will show you the config changes you need to apply.

**Updated answer to show correct configuration based on comment below**

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
  <runtimePolicies>
    <ignoredTypes>
      <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"></add>
    </ignoredTypes>
  </runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

Comment: when i define the runtimepolicies in glimpse section in web.config, i got run time error "unrecognized element" please give a solution for that

Comment: could you show the relevant parts of your web.config in your question? Because it is hard to see what is wrong with the config if we can't see it

Comment: This is the code in web.config i used .
<glimpse defaultruntimepolicy="On" endpointbaseuri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <runtimepolicies>
        <ignoredtypes>
            <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet">
        </add></ignoredtypes>
    </runtimepolicies>
</glimpse>

Comment: ok, I see what the problem is. You need to make sure you use the correct casing for your configuration elements and attributes. I've updated the answer to show you the correct configuration for your case. But if you are not sure about the case, then certainly have a look at the configuration tool on glimpse.axd for further help.